# How to fix errors in HTML file on eclipse?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I am building a dynamic web project in eclipse Java EE and I added the external files of CodeMirror editor. I tried to use the external files of CodeMirror and it works good, but when I add the CodeMirror editor under WebContent 3 errors appear in index.html.

The code :

```
    #types
    immutable Color{T<:Number}
      r::T
      g::T
      b::T
    end

The error at the second line:

> Multiple annotations found at this line :

>   - Start tag (<:Number>) not closed properly, expected '>'.
>   - Invalid location of text (}) in tag (<:Number>).
>   - Unknown tag (:Number).

The external files of CodeMirror work well but only when I add them to eclipse, it gives these errors inside the external files. How could I fix them?

edit:
this is all code :



       <!doctype html>

    <title>CodeMirror: Julia mode</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="../../doc/docs.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src="../../lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="julia.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.CodeMirror {border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}</style>
    <div id=nav>
      <a href="http://codemirror.net"><h1>CodeMirror</h1><img id=logo src="../../doc/logo.png"></a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="../../index.html">Home</a>
        <li><a href="../../doc/manual.html">Manual</a>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror">Code</a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Language modes</a>
        <li><a class=active href="#">Julia</a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <article>
    <h2>Julia mode</h2>

        <div><textarea id="code" name="code">
    #numbers
    1234
    1234im
    .234
    .234im
    2.23im
    2.3f3
    23e2
    0x234

    #strings
    'a'
    "asdf"
    r"regex"
    b"bytestring"

    """
    multiline string
    """

    #identifiers
    a
    as123
    function_name!

    #unicode identifiers
    # a = x\ddot
    a⃗ = ẍ
    # a = v\dot
    a⃗ = v̇
    #F\vec = m \cdotp a\vec
    F⃗ = m·a⃗

    #literal identifier multiples
    3x
    4[1, 2, 3]

    #dicts and indexing
    x=[1, 2, 3]
    x[end-1]
    x={"julia"=>"language of technical computing"}


    #exception handling
    try
      f()
    catch
      @printf "Error"
    finally
      g()
    end

    #types
    immutable Color{T<:Number}
      r::T
      g::T
      b::T
    end

    #functions
    function change!(x::Vector{Float64})
      for i = 1:length(x)
        x[i] *= 2
      end
    end

    #function invocation
    f('b', (2, 3)...)

    #operators
    |=
    &=
    ^=
    \-
    %=
    *=
    +=
    -=
    <=
    >=
    !=
    ==
    %
    *
    +
    -
    <
    >
    !
    =
    |
    &
    ^
    \
    ?
    ~
    :
    $
    <:
    .<
    .>
    <<
    <<=
    >>
    >>>>
    >>=
    >>>=
    <<=
    <<<=
    .<=
    .>=
    .==
    ->
    //
    in
    ...
    //
    :=
    .//=
    .*=
    ./=
    .^=
    .%=
    .+=
    .-=
    \=
    \\=
    ||
    ===
    &&
    |=
    .|=
    <:
    >:
    |>
    <|
    ::
    x ? y : z

    #macros
    @spawnat 2 1+1
    @eval(:x)

    #keywords and operators
    if else elseif while for
     begin let end do
    try catch finally return break continue
    global local const 
    export import importall using
    function macro module baremodule 
    type immutable quote
    true false enumerate


        </textarea></div>
        <script>
          var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            mode: {name: "julia",
                   },
            lineNumbers: true,
            indentUnit: 4,
            matchBrackets: true
          });
        </script>

        <p><strong>MIME types defined:</strong> <code>text/x-julia</code>.</p>
    </article>
```

EDIT :
[the first error he said processing instruction not closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX1ed.png)

[the second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ZvS.png)

the all instruction in error 2:

```
cancast:{nw:x$"";if[not x in"BXCS";nw:(min 0#;max 0#;::)@\:nw];$[not any nw in x$(11&count y)#y;$[11<count y;not any nw in x$y;1b];0b]}
```

Comment: Instead of screenshots just add the relevant code to your question. Try to put an "\" before the "<", you said it was HTML, then eclipse tries to parse it as an html tag.

Comment: I put it  {T\<:Number}  but the error not be remove:( the code it very big so I can't put it in my question.

Comment: there are any add to eclipse to skip these error ?all files work fine ... but I don't knew why eclipse make errors ...

Comment: Yes the name of file index.html embedded in codemirror files , but eclipse make error on it

Comment: I will edit My question and embdedd all code in index.html  @Ephi

Comment: replace '<' by &lt; in "<:Number"

Comment: I replace '<' by &lt; in "<:Number" ,But  don't work :( @Ephi

Comment: Still the same error at the same point ? Did you saved your file ? Eclipse doesn't systematicly parse files when they're not saved.

Comment: yes it remove after I save the file thank you

Comment: please I edit My Question There are 2 error in another index.html can you see if you can solve it @Ephi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters such as '<' or '>' are used to define HTML tags, etc, and therefore will be treated as code.

However, if you want to write '<', '>' as **text**, you must use the HTML codes for those characters. For exemple, '<' will become `&lt;`,
'>' will become `&gt;`. By replacing those characters by their corresponding code, they will not be recognized as HTML pure code.

At http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm you will find a more complete list of those codes. This principle is called "HTML escape".

Comment: Ok , I will see your link and try to solve the 2 error , thanks for your help @Ephi

Comment: There is probably tools to do it automaticaly, try to search for one

Comment: Ok , Thank you very much